# Запятая в сочетании "такого понятия как"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Эти дети не знают такого понятия(,) как родители.

Требуется ли запятая перед "как" и правильно ли оформление предложение в целом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше написать так: ***Эти дети не знают такого слова, как родители.***

Или: ***Этим детям незнакомо такое понятие, как родители.***

Корректность сочетания *знать понятие* вызывает сомнение.

Запятая ставится при повторе *такого...как*.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

3. Сравнительный оборот с союзом как выделяется запятыми в следующих случаях:

2) если в основной части предложения имеется **указательное слово (так, такой, тот, столь)**: Я всё сделаю, чтобы стать такой, как она (Пан.);